# Image upload in database using codignitor

Tags: php

I want to save images in database (MYsql) using BLOB Field by uploading through form in web and how it could be display after uploading.i know it is a bad practice but situation demands me to do that. i am using codignitor framework.
if anybody know how to achieve this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Try this it will help you https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/

Comment: Show some code you have tried..!!

Comment: Can you please put your code what you have tried?

Comment: so far i have tried,  $get_image =$this->input->post(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
  // $encoded_value_of_image='data:image/;base64,' base64_encode($get_image);
  $id = $this->input->post('rowid');
        $data = array(
            'test' => $get_image,
    'mrn_remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks'),

        ); but image is not displaying, and i have used following code : <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=echo base64_encode($data[0]->test); ?>">

Comment: this link 'formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image' will not work for me as i have to store image in database blob field not in folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Save your image in the data base

```
   $image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
    $data=file_get_contents($image);
    $string=base64_encode($data);

    $data=array("image"=>$string);
    $this->load->model('insert');
    $this->insert->insertImage($data);
```

Step 2: Read the base64 string from the database and load in your view

```
$img1=base64_decode($img);//$img is the data from database 
$formImage = imagecreatefromstring($img1);
if ($formImage !== false) 
  {
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($formImage);
imagedestroy($formImage);
}
else
{
echo 'An error occurred.';
 }
```

Comment: hi thanks for the solution but whenever i include this line : imagecreatefromstring($img1) in my code it throws php Error. do u have any idea why it is so? however i am getting the image and encoded form when i checked but my code exection stops fro  this line. please help me out.

Comment: it just put a blank page

Comment: installed GD library?